# IBM Rhapsody terminates the animation when an operation is called from another block

Tags: uml, rhapsody, sysml

I am new to Rahpsody/SysMl and I would like your support.

I have two blocks (B and C) that are parts of a bigger Block (A).

My goal is to call (from B) an operation (belonging to C) that will do some processing and returns a value.

I am not sure whether I need to create a triggered operation or a just simple one, so I went with the triggered option. I created a triggered operation in Block C and created an association relationship between Block B & C.
Then from Block B's state machine I called the triggered operation.

The model builds successfully but during the simulation when the time comes to call the triggered operation, the simulation just terminates without any error message.
If I remove the operation call, the simulation works normally.

Guys, am I missing something here ?

P.S : I'm using IBM Rhapsody 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An association between B and C defines that *some* instances of B can be linked to *some* instances of C. It doesn‘t mean that *all* instances are linked. Therefore, the simulation engine cannot know, that you want the two instances who happen to be part of an instance of A to be linked. You have to specify this.

The easiest way to do it, is to model a connector between the parts of A in an internal block diagram. Then you have to type the connector with the association.

I haven’t tried whether Rhapsody will use this information. However, this is as it is specified in the Precise Semantics of Composite Structures specification, which supplements the UML and SysML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works :D !! 
Does this mean I should create a connection/association pair for each operation I want to call from the other part ? 
Another thing is that a triggered operation does not allow to specify an implementation, should I use a simple operation ?

Comment: The connection defines that the parts shall be linked. If one part shall call operations on another part, there must be a link. All public operations can then be called accross this link.

I don't know what Rhapsody means with "triggered operation". You say, that it cannot have an implementation. I guess you mean, it cannot have a behavior assigned directly as a method. This is true for operations used _in_ a trigger of a transition. So, calling the operation _triggers_ a transition, which in turn has the effect of invoking an _implementation_ behavior or simply transitioning to a new state.

Comment: Your assumption about "triggered operations" in Rhapsody is correct. 
My initial objective was to call a behavior that returns a value to its caller (B in the example), the problem with simple operations is that I was not able to see any values being returned to 'B' in the associated sequence diagram. That's why I used at the end these "triggered operations" since they have a "reply" feature that can be seen in the sequence diagram. 
Is it normal not to see the return value in the sequence diagram using simple operations ?

Comment: No, this is not normal. An operation that is called synchroneously should create an implicit reply message, when it ends.